# Sort multidimensional Array, merge by keys in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge, key

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ben
            [matchedMovie] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Saw
                    [genre] => Horror
                    [patheMovie] => Texas Chainsaw 3D
                    [patheMovieGenre] => Horror
                    [score] => 100.00
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ben 
            [matchedMovie] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Shooter
                    [genre] => Action, Thriller
                    [patheMovie] => The Shining
                    [patheMovieGenre] => Horror, Suspense/Thriller 
                    [score] => 52.38
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dick
            [matchedMovie] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Resident Evil Movie
                    [genre] => Action/Horror
                    [patheMovie] => Texas Chainsaw 3D
                    [patheMovieGenre] => Horror
                    [score] => 63.16
                )

        )
)
```

I want to sort it something like this (don't know if i got it exactly right):

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Ben
                [matchedMovie][0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Saw
                        [genre] => Horror
                        [patheMovie] => Texas Chainsaw 3D
                        [patheMovieGenre] => Horror
                        [score] => 100.00
                    )

                [matchedMovie][1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Shooter
                        [genre] => Action, Thriller
                        [patheMovie] => The Shining
                        [patheMovieGenre] => Horror, Suspense/Thriller 
                        [score] => 52.38
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dick
                [matchedMovie][0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Resident Evil Movie
                        [genre] => Action/Horror
                        [patheMovie] => Texas Chainsaw 3D
                        [patheMovieGenre] => Horror
                        [score] => 63.16
                    ) 
            )
    )
```

So that the matchedMovie arrays are under the same name.
How should i do this?

I have tried this function:

```
function group_by_key($array) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array as $sub) {
            foreach ($sub as $k => $v) {
                $result[$k][] = $v;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: So you mention `sort` in your title, but not in your question.  Is there actually some sort of sort you are trying to do as well?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the difference between the two arrays. Perhaps you could outline in words what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry, my english is not the best. I will try to explain it. As you can see in the first multidimensional array that there is a name twice mentioned. I want to merge the matchedMovie of that second name with the first. So that its all under the same name and every name is unique.

Comment: you would need to do the comparison if to see if they have the same 'name' value. unless you are using the value of 'name' as the key, then you can directly set them to the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick stab at it.

```
function group_by_key($array){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $row){
        if(!isset($result[$row['name']]){
            $result[$row['name']] = array(
                'name'=>$row['name'],
                'matchedMovie'=>array($row['matchedMovie'])
            );
        } else {
            $result[$row['name']]['matchedMovie'][] = $row['matchedMovie'];
        }
    }
    return array_values($result);
}
```